# Update state with object from key input [React]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm trying to update the state of my component based on key inputs, and pass it to another component.

I can get call `keyboardInput()` and console.log the correctly when one of the arrow keys are pressed, however I cannot get the returned value to render in `<p>The current input is: {this.keyboardInput}</p>`

E.g. `return {'Y': 1};` when the up key is pressed, but nothing appears in the `<p>` element

I believe I'm missing some understanding when it comes to the `componentWillReceiveProps` function, but I'm at a loss.

Could it be that `keyboardInput` is returning an object not a string value? But even when I change the return to just be a string, I still cannot get it to render.

What am I missing here?

Thanks,

```
class GameBoard extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            test: {},
        };
    }

    // Captures event from main window
        keyboardInput = (e) => {

            const code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;

            // Change X and Y values
            if (code === 38) { //up key
                return {'Y': 1};
            } else if (code === 40) { //down key
                return {'Y': -1};
            } else if (code === 37) { // left key
                return {'X': 1};
            } else if (code === 39) { // right key
                return {'X': -1};
            }
        };

    componentWillMount() {
        window.addEventListener('keydown', this.keyboardInput);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('keydown', this.keyboardInput);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState.test = this.keyboardInput(nextProps);
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <p>The current input is: {this.keyboardInput}</p>
                <Ball/>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

class App extends Component {

  render() {

      const boardStyle = {
          'position': 'absolute',
          'backgroundColor': '#7f8c8d',
          'height': '100%',
          'width': '100%',

      };

    return (
      <div>
        <header>
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to Moving Objects</h1>
        </header>
          <div style={boardStyle}>
              <GameBoard/>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Props are passed down from the parent component. They are irrelevant here. What you'll want to do is actually change the state inside `keyboardInput`, as opposed to returning the object into nirvana. (nowhere). You need to 1. look up how `setState()` is used 2. do that inside your `keyboardInput`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there's some misunderstanding about React/JS constructs in general here.

Hopefully the below will help you along, but you should definitely take a closer look at the React docs to get a better handle on what you're doing.

`{this.keyboardInput}` in your `render` function doesn't actually refer to anything here - `this` is referring to your `GameBoard` class, and then you're trying to access some member - be it a function, variable, whatever - called `keyboardInput`. You don't have one.

With React, what you would want to access is `{this.state.keyboardInput}` - what that is saying is this: In `this` (the GameBoard), I want to access its current `state`. In that `state`, there is a field called `keyboardInput`. Render that.

```
<p> The current input is: {this.state.keyboardInput} </p>
```

The second step is to actually  **set**  that state. It looks like you have calling your function `keyboardInput` down when the eventlistener picks up an event, but I think this is part of your issue: `keyboardInput` would be much better named something like `onKeyboardInput` or `handleKeyboardInput`.

Remember how we wanted to set the state? Inside that function, we're going to have to use React's [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) function - it would look something like this:

```
handleKeyboardInput = (e) => {
        const code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;

        if (code === 38) { //up key
            this.setState({ keyboardInput: {'Y', -1 }});
        }
}
```

This function is now saying, "Hey `GameBoard`, your state is going to now have a field `keyboardInput`, which will look like the object `{ 'Y', -1 }`."

Note that `this` in `keyboardInput` wants to refer to React's component, so we'll have to bind this in our listeners:

```
componentWillMount() {
        window.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyboardInput.bind(this));
}
```

All we're doing here is telling `handleKeyboardInput` to use the same `this` as `componentWillMount`. `this` in `componentWillMount` refers to our `GameBoard` component, so `this` in `handleKeyboardInput` will also refer to the `GameBoard`. We want this because `handleKeyboardInput` wants to call `GameBoard`'s `.setState` function.

In general, that's how the flow of React goes: you'll want to set some `state` on a component using `setState`. After that's done, you can read it out in your `render` function (or any other function for that matter) by saying `this.state.foobar`.

In this example, we start at our listener. We see a keypress event, and say, go handle whatever we need to do at `handleKeyboardInput`! `handleKeyboardInput` says `GameBoard`! Your state is `keyboardInput: foo`. All the while, render is looking `GameBoard`'s state (the `keyboardInput`!) to display.

Like I said, this is a pretty informal rundown of states in React - definitely take a look at React's documentation, and maybe work through an example project they have to really let it sink in.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. I'll look over the docs some more. Cheers!

Comment: why don't you bound the handleKeyboardInput method in the constructor?